# Android&Quickblox: What is the dependency for FCMService?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging, quickblox

I need to `import com.quickblox.messages.services.fcm.QBFcmPushListenerService`
but the dependency is missing. This is my gradle file:

```
....
dependencies {
    ....
    compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.5.1@aar") {
         transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:2.5.1@aar'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:2.5.1@aar'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:2.5.1@aar'
}
....
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need use messages SDK:

```
compile ("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.3.0" )
```

Available from source:

```
 repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
    }
}
```

QBFcmPushListenerService is available on **SDK version >= 3.2**

Answer (score -1):

For using QBFcmPushListenerService use QB SDK version 3.2 Besides there is a new feature [Auto subscription](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android#Setup_Push_Notifications_SDK_3.2_-_Auto_subscription)